# InstallAware - How to Execute custom program in Before Remove Previous Installation

Tags: uninstallation, execution, installaware

Is there a way to Execute a custom program before InstallaWare removes the previous version of the my Application?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in the software with this name : Advanced Options -> Run Programs. 
That's what you want.
Here is official manual : http://www.installaware.com/blog/?p=16